# matching two array data and get sum of it! (algorithm...?)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to match time and date 
and result should be sum of time for each date...
for example...06/27 - should be sum of 30 and 90...so on. 
How can I do that...

```
var array_date=["2017/06/27","2017/06/26","2017/06/27","2017/06/26","2017/06/28"]

var array_time=["30","50","90","120","20"]

var obj = array_date;
for (var i = 0 in obj) {
  console.log("rr:"+obj[i]);
}

//To filter date I used below method...anyway. 
var cleanArray = displayed_date.filter((value,index,self)=>{ return (self.indexOf(value) === index )});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, since you're doing addition, best to convert your strings to numbers:

```
array_time = array_time.map(t=> +t);
```

Next, group and sum the times by date:

```
let data = array_date.reduce((acc, d, i)=> {
    if(acc.hasOwnProperty(d)) acc[d] += array_time[i];
    else acc[d] = array_time[i];
    return acc;
}, {});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w0312ng7/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just like this:

```
       <script>
        array_date=["2017/06/27","2017/06/26","2017/06/27","2017/06/26","2017/06/28"];

        array_time=["30","50","90","120","20"];

        var oData = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < array_date.length; i++ ){

            if(Object.keys(oData).length > 0){
              var icount = 0;
              for(var x = 0; x < Object.keys(oData).length; x++){

                if(oData[x]['date'] == array_date[i]){
                  oData[x]['sum'] = parseInt(oData[x]['sum']) + parseInt(array_time[i]);
                  icount++;
                }
              }

              if(icount == 0){
                var oCreate = {"date":array_date[i], "sum":parseInt(array_time[i])}

                  oData.push(oCreate);
              }

            }else{
              var oCreate = {"date":array_date[i], "sum":parseInt(array_time[i])}

              oData.push(oCreate);
            }

        }

        console.log(JSON.stringify(oData)); //oData is the final variable answer here.

   </script>
```

Hope it will help.